# Fastest way to duplicate or copy or back up a directory with TB of data (image files) in it

Tags: linux, file-transfer, rsync, cp, mv

Hi can you suggest an very efficient and high performance option to copy files (TB of data in the form of images are present) from one disk to another.

I saw options like cp, rsync etc., but would like to have a second opinion from you guys who have tried and tested such a scenario reliably.

I also have a requirement as below:

1. Primary disk -> where the files are stored from after capture
2. Secondary disk which uses rsync to back up from primary disk.
3. Third disk which will now back up Secondary disk and then delete unwanted files from primary so that secondary and third disk will sync up again

Note: 1. Please consider server utilization also as the image files will also be read in parallel by other processes. 2. I am try to back up from secondary disk to third. Need your advice for the 3 step

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately disk copying is slow.  There is no cheap way around this.

It does seem like RSYNC is a good way to go because you are not continually wanting to copy all the data on the disk.   You might want to check that your rsync is not skipping based on checksum (ie no -c or --checksum flag) assuming you can rely on timestamps and filesize.  If file contents changes (which sounds unlikely), you may get a significant speedup by doing "--inplace --no-whole-file" to only copy the bits that have changed.

Of-course, there are other strategies worth considering at a block level.  Changing to ZFS (or DRBD or Gluster or MooseFS) and replicating data at a block level may land up being more efficient depending on what kind of changes you are doing, how bursty your traffic is etc.

Comment: Thanks for the approach. I will try to explore the other options you have shared. Additionally the files will never be modified. They may be deleted but never modified. So what would you suggest me.